# Ruby 2.0 Create Multipart Form Data

Tags: multipartform-data, ruby-2.0

I have written RUBY code for creating multipart form data request. It is working perfectly in ruby 1.9.3, but it is raising error in ruby 2.0 patch 247 and patch 0.

The error is,

```
/home/mohanrajr/Ruby/multipart/multipart_stream.rb:16:in `read': wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) (ArgumentError)
    from /home/mohanrajr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/generic_request.rb:205:in `copy_stream'
    from /home/mohanrajr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/generic_request.rb:205:in `send_request_with_body_stream'
    from /home/mohanrajr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/generic_request.rb:132:in `exec'
    from /home/mohanrajr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1404:in `block in transport_request'
    from /home/mohanrajr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1403:in `catch'
    from /home/mohanrajr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1403:in `transport_request'
    from /home/mohanrajr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1376:in `request'
    from /home/mohanrajr/Ruby/multipart/multipart.rb:38:in `block in post'
    from /home/mohanrajr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
    from /home/mohanrajr/Ruby/multipart/multipart.rb:38:in `post'
    from multipart_post.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Could you post the content of `multipart_stream.rb`?